# Converting a JavaScript array to JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

So I have an array that looks like this:

```js
var me = [
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'}
];
```

How do I convert this to a JSON object starting with '{' and ending with '}'

Comment: What property names would you want? It doesn't make sense to try to convert a JavaScript array into a JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

With `JSON.stringify`?

```
var me =[
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
    {'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'}
];

console.log(JSON.stringify(me));    // returns whole JSON.
console.log(JSON.stringify(me[0])); // returns what you want, 'starting with {}'.

//    if you want to start with {} with all data:
console.log(JSON.stringify({me:me}));
```

Comment: The question is asking to convert the *array* to a JSON object, not one of the objects inside it.

Comment: He requested to start with {}.

Comment: Indeed. The question doesn't make sense. I don't think it is answerable in its current state.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
JSON.stringify(me.reduce(function(o, v, i) {
    o[i] = v;
    return o;
}, {}));
```

Comment: That won't work. That will give you a JSON array, not an object.

Comment: After editing, it converts one of the objects in the array to a JSON object instead of converting the array to one.

Comment: That now does what the question is asking. The requirement is still bizarre though.

Comment: True that... Really dunno why the OP needs this kind of black magic.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(me);
```

**UPDATED**

```
var me =[
{'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
{'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
{'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'},
{'we':'me','see':'tree','lee':'bee'}
];


var myjson={'list':""}
myjson.list=me;
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(myjson);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

Comment: That won't work. That will give you a JSON array, not an object.

Comment: yaa you right @Quentin